# jquery select2 plugin regex for allowed characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

Is there anyway to define a set of "allowed" characters for user input? For e.g. alphanumeric input only. Can't seem to find it within the official documentation

Answer (score 4):

You can accomplish this using the createSearchChoice option, which allows you to define a custom function to create tags from user input. To not allow tags containing other than alphanumeric characters, the select2 should be initialized as:

```
$("#mySelect").select2({
            createSearchChoice: function(term) {
                if(term.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/g))
                    return { id: term, text: term };
            },
            formatNoMatches: "Enter valid format text"})
```

If the user is typing text that contains non-alphanumeric characters, the dropdown below the select2 will show no matches. It's not necessary to specify a custom formatNoMatches but it is more helpful for the user than the default "No matches found" to figure out why their input isn't being accepted.

**Update:**

As of select2 version ~ `4.0` this function is now called `createTag`

Comment: For people coming here now, this option has been renamed to `createTag` as of [this release](https://github.com/select2/select2/releases/tag/4.0.0-beta.2). `term` is also now in the form of `{term: 'string'}`.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find anything about put a mask/regex on the input where you type. 
But you can do it on the 'open' event provided by select2.
Something like this:

```
$('select of the select2 input or select').on('select2-open',function(e){
    // apply your mask on this element -> $('.select2-input')
});
```

Hope it helps you.
Bye

Answer (score 0):

Today I was finding a way to apply a custom mask on the input that appear in the dropdown (select2 v3), and I found this topic.

After some research on [official doc](http://select2.github.io/select2/#documentation) I saw the method `select2("container")`, and looking the source code I found `select2("dropdown")` (not present on doc).

So, my final code is (for contribution purpose):

```
$('my-select2').on('select2-open',function(e){
    var input = $(this).select2("dropdown").find('.select2-input');
    // ...
});
```