# How to detect either the value is from select option or dynamically inputed. - select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am using `select2` library and has enabled the tag options to true. I have the code as follows:

```
<select class="select2" name="location">
    @foreacg($location as $lk => $lv)
      <option value="{{$lv->id}}">{{$lv->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>

<script>
$(function(){
   $(".select2").select2({
     tags: true
   });
})
</scipt>
```

The select option print something like:

```
      <option value="1">1st Floor</option>
      <option value="2">Window</option>
      <option value="3">Balcony</option>
      <option value="4">Staircase</option>
      <option value="5">2nd Floor</option>
```

If user select one of the predefined option the value (location id) of that selected option will be used for further processing.

In other case, if user insert new dynamic option then this value will be first inserted into location table and the id of that location will be used for processing.

But the main problem I faced is **how to determine if the posted value is either from one of the predefined option or from the new dynamic option**.

let's say if user insert `3` In this case this 3 should be inserted into location and the location id should be used. How can I distinguish that this `3` is new inputed value and not the value from the option as in both case I received the value `3` in `$request->location`.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h4jbcapo/)

Comment: as simple as not taking an integer as possible custom input.

Comment: Could you suggest such jquery validition which check the input value must have at least one alphabetic character

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jquery select2 plugin regex for allowed characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21592557/jquery-select2-plugin-regex-for-allowed-characters)

Comment: @N69S No it does not work. It is generating error `term.match is not a function in console.log`. https://jsfiddle.net/h4jbcapo/

Comment: as the comment on the answer says "For people coming here now, this option has been renamed to createTag as of this release. term is also now in the form of {term: 'string'}" i suggest you directly check the plugin documentation for it.